# What is the purpose of the System Data Archiver feature?

Tags: windows-server-2019, programsandfeatures

I am looking to remove unnecessary roles and features from Windows 2019 systems
and there is a new feature named System Data Archiver which is installed by default.

The official description says:

> Provides services to collect and archive Windows Server system data.

Does anybody know a little more about this feature, especially what happens if this feature is uninstalled?

Comment: Even Google can't find anything relevant about this. Upvoted.

Comment: I guess we need to uninstall it and wait for something bad to happen... :-) But it's a new feature, meaning everything was working fine without it until Windows 2019. We should probably expect to miss some improvements or that new functionalities do not work as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **System Data Archiver** gathers data and provide them to the **System Insight** feature.
(Thanks to Yilia Zhao (MSFT CSG) who led me to the answer)

## Consequences of uninstalling the feature

If you uninstall the **System Data Archiver** feature the **System Insight** will log the following type of errors:

```
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-System-Insights
Id           : 147
Message      : Unable to load DLLs required to gather data for capability 'CPU capacity forecasting'. Potential issues: Feature 'System-DataArchiver' is uninstalled. if so, install the 'System-DataArchiver' feature.
```

Furthermore, when you uninstall the **System Data Archiver** feature it removes the collected data too. You must then wait at least 6 days after reinstalling it before **System Insight** can make a forecast.